# Why do I have 500 ERR on my Prestashop API?

Tags: php, prestashop

I have a big problem. I tried to put an API on my website (built with PrestaShop 8.0.2)

But it throws an error when I submit the form.

Here are the errors :

> 500    POST /connexion3.php HTTP/1.0
> AH01215: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PrestaShopWebserviceException: HTTP XML response is not parsable: array (: /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper, referer: https://dev.raph.fun/
> AH01215: 'message' => 'Start tag expected, \'<\' not found: /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper, referer: https://dev.raph.fun/

Here is my login HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page client</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Page client</h1>
    <form id="loginForm" action="https://raph.fun/connexion3.php" method="POST">
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br><br>
        <label for="password">Mot de passe:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Se connecter">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here my PHP file :

```
<?php

require_once('/var/www/vhosts/raph.fun/httpdocs/PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

$url = "https://raph.fun"; // PS shop domain without "/api"
$key = "MY-API-KEY";          //replaced my API key for asking question
$debug = false; //true;

// get information from PrestaShop
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($url, $key, $debug);

$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
//$password = '123456789';  
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

$optUser = array(
    'resource' => 'customers',
    'filter[email]' => '[' . $email . ']',
    'display' => '[id,email,lastname,firstname,passwd]'
);

$resultUser = ($webService->get($optUser));

foreach ($resultUser->customers->customer as $info) {

    if (password_verify($password, $info->passwd) == true) {
    session_start();
        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = 'succes';
        $response['message'] = "You did it!";
        setcookie("userId", $info->id);
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
    $response = array();
        $response['status'] = 'error';
        $response['message'] = 'Wrong password';
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}

?>
```

My response :

```xml
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<customers>
<customer>
<id>
<![CDATA[ 15 ]]>
</id>
<passwd>
<![CDATA[ $2y$10$VNHbe8mjOBeDbV1xnLQlX.8KZJWCMgkGQIurFq3QGBUrxHbPbOoyW ]]>
</passwd>
<lastname>
<![CDATA[ test ]]>
</lastname>
<firstname>
<![CDATA[ test ]]>
</firstname>
<email>
<![CDATA[ test@gmail.com ]]>
</email>
</customer>
</customers>
</prestashop>
```

It would be great if someone could help me, i'm on this since a week... Thanks

I searched on google night and day if someone had the same problem, but I couldn't find any suitable and working idea. I'm new in PHP and APIs

Comment: Could you please post the XML-Response that causes the error?

Comment: Hello, I added it in my original post. Thanks

Comment: Well, that is valid XML.

Comment: Where and how exactly did you verify that this was the XML response?

Comment: I was able to access it with my ws_key, I put it manually in the link. I think it's because my ws_key is not verified by the script so it throws 401 and after that the 500 ERR